# Simple finite difference employing Maccormack technique

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, numpy, numerical-methods

I am relatively new to programming and while I am fairly comfortable with the math, I cannot say with confidence that I feel the same way with programming. Anyway here is a simple finite difference employing Maccormack technique. There are some lines with similar commands and I am sure there is a way to make this more compact. Especially with for loops and making some lines disappear due to redundancy which I cannot figure out.

```
import numpy as np

dx=0.1
t_max=3.1
dt=.1
gamma=1.4
C=0.5

k=np.arange(0,t_max,dt)
x=np.arange(0,3.1,dx)

s=len(x)
r=len(k)


T=1-0.2314*x  #initial condition
rho=1-0.3146*x #initial condition
V=(0.1+1.09*x)*np.sqrt(T)   #initial condition 




rho_t=np.zeros([s])
V_t=np.zeros([s])
T_t=np.zeros([s])
t=np.ones([s])
rho_bar=np.ones([s])
V_bar=np.ones([s])
T_bar=np.ones([s])
rho_tbar=np.ones([s])
V_tbar=np.ones([s])
T_tbar=np.ones([s])
rho_avg=np.ones([s])
T_avg=np.ones([s])
V_avg=np.ones([s])
rho_r=np.zeros([s,r])
V_r=np.zeros([s,r])
T_r=np.zeros([s,r])


for n in range(0,r): #time step
    V[0]=2*V[1]-V[2]  # Subsonic Inflow Boundary
    V[30]=2*V[29]-V[28] # Supersonic Outflow Boundary
    rho[30]=2*rho[29]-rho[28] # Supersonic Outflow Boundary
    T[30]=2*T[29]-T[28] # Supersonic Outflow Boundary
    V_r[:,n]=V # compliation of flowfield variable at each timestep
    T_r[:,n]=T # compliation of flowfield variable at each timestep
    rho_r[:,n]=rho # compliation of flowfield variable at each timestep
    for i in range(1,s-1):
# Predictor Step
        rho_t[i]=-rho[i]/dx*(V[i+1]-V[i])-rho[i]*V[i]/dx*(np.log1p(A[i+1])-np.log1p(A[i]))-V[i]/dx*(rho[i+1]-rho[i])
        V_t[i]=-V[i]/dx*(V[i+1]-V[i])-1/gamma*((T[i+1]-T[i])/dx+T[i]/rho[i]/dx*(rho[i+1]-rho[i]))
        T_t[i]=-V[i]/dx*(T[i+1]-T[i])-(gamma-1)*T[i]*((V[i+1]-V[i])/dx+V[i]/dx*(np.log1p(A[i+1])-np.log1p(A[i])))

        t[i]=C*dx/(np.sqrt(T[i])+V[i]) # time step

        rho_bar[i]=rho[i]+rho_t[i]*min(t)
        V_bar[i]=V[i]+V_t[i]*min(t)
        T_bar[i]=T[i]+T_t[i]*min(t) 

        rho_tbar[i]=-rho_bar[i]/dx*(V_bar[i]-V_bar[i-1])-rho_bar[i]*V_bar[i]/dx*(np.log1p(A[i])-np.log1p(A[i-1]))-V_bar[i]/dx*(rho_bar[i]-rho_bar[i-1]) #t=t+dt
        V_tbar[i]=-V_bar[i]/dx*(V_bar[i]-V_bar[i-1])-1/gamma*((T_bar[i]-T[i-1])/dx+T_bar[i]/rho_bar[i]/dx*(rho_bar[i]-rho[i-1]))    #t=t+dt
        T_tbar[i]=-V_bar[i]/dx*(T_bar[i]-T_bar[i-1])-(gamma-1)*T_bar[i]*((V[i]-V[i-1])/dx+V_bar[i]/dx*(np.log1p(A[i])-np.log1p(A[i-1])))   #t=t+dt

        rho_avg[i]=0.5*(rho_t[i]+rho_tbar[i])
        T_avg[i]=0.5*(T_t[i]+T_tbar[i])
        V_avg[i]=0.5*(V_t[i]+V_tbar[i])

        t[i]=C*dx/(np.sqrt(T[i])+V[i]) # time step

        rho[i]=rho[i]+rho_avg[i]*min(t)
        V[i]=V[i]+V_avg[i]*min(t)
        T[i]=T[i]+T_avg[i]*min(t)
```

Comment: It would help if you could write the equation this solves. This way some of your names might become easier to understand. For example `rho_bar` is probably not a bad name, but without knowing what kind of density it is, it is quite hard to understand.

Comment: I'd start by trying to rewrite the `i` loop.  Does it have to be a loop? A quick read suggests that `rho_t` can be calculated with expressions like `V[1:]-V[:-1]` without a loop.  I also don't see a serial dependence in `rho_tbar`.